# Error de conexión a Firebird en JavaScript : "Incompatible wire encryption levels requested on client and server", "Firebird 3.0" y "firebird@1.1.5"

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebird

Ya intente solucionarlo cambiando el valor del archivo de configuración "firebird.conf" poniendo
"WireCrypt = Enabled" pero me sigue marcando el mismo error, la versión que tengo de Firebird es la 3.0 y la dependencia de nodejs es "node-firebird@1.1.5"

Comment: El error dice que los niveles de encripción solicitados en el cliente y en el servidor son incompatibles. Vendría bien ver cómo está configurado el servidor y cómo estás configurando la conexión del lado del cliente (de la base de datos, en nodejs). Debes tener en cuenta que los cambios en `firebird.conf` se aplican solo después de reiniciar el servicio (suponiendo que usas superclassic o superserver).